# Angular app works locally but not on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

When I start my Angular 10 app locally with `ng s -o` it works fine and it's able to connect to my backend, which is running on Heroku.

But when I deploy it on firebase it only displays the frontend parts and doesn't get the data from the backend anymore. The weird thing is that it tries to get the data from my local backend on `localhost:8090`. But I replaced every localhost URL in my Angular App with the URL to my Heroku App:

[image: error message]

[image: Network analysis showing request to localhost:8090]

When I run the Angular app locally on `localhost:4200` I can see in the network analysis in the browser console that all http requests are made to the Heroku URL:

[image: Network analysis when running my Angular app locally]

I saved all changes in my Angular folder where I changed the URLs from localhost to the Heroku URL, I then pushed everything to git (don't know if that makes a difference), then deleted the dist folder of my Angular App completely, then ran again `ng build --prod` and `firebase deploy`. But still, my on firebase deployed app on https://studileih-ceb70.web.app/ seems to keep making the request to `https://localhost:8090/` instead of my Heroku URL (https://studileih-heroku.herokuapp.com/).
I used the search function of Visual Studio to see, if I forgot to replace a localhost URL in my project, but I replaced them all.

Additional info: When using the on firebase deployed app, the error appears for all http requests, not only for the one shown above for `http://localhost:8090/products`: [image: other failing requests on firebase] -> they should all be made to `https://studileih-heroku.herokuapp.com/` instead of `localhost`.

**Why does my deployed app still make requests to `localhost` when I removed all localhost URLs from my app before building + deploying it?**

Comment: "Why does my deployed app still make requests to localhost when I removed all localhost URLs from my app before building + deploying it?" - well... you clearly didn't..? Your app doesn't just make up URL's right?

Comment: yes... you're right. I will try to make a complete new project on firebase quickly probably that will solve it.

Comment: Sorry man - I wasn't trying to be gnarly.. but you probably have too much going on that makes stuff confusing. You plan is solid - start over.

Comment: oh it worked. I just had to run `firebase use --add`again and give a new alias, then deploy it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that just running `firebase deploy` wasn't enough, I also had to run `firebase use --add` and give a new alias for the project before deploying it again. Then it worked.